# Как в скрипт python принять параметры

Tags: python

может кто даст коротенький примерчик. что должно быть прописано в скрипте python что бы он принял параметр "из вне". 
прочитал что как бы def , опробовал не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sys.argv example](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/python-sys-argv/)

[sys.argv documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

> sys.argv is a list in Python, which
> contains the command-line arguments
> passed to the script.
>
> With the len(sys.argv) function you
> can count the number of arguments.
>
> If you are gonna work with command
> line arguments, you probably want to 
> use sys.argv.
>
> To use sys.argv, you will first have
> to import the sys module.

Answer (score 3):

В стандартной библиотеке питона есть модуль [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Пример:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Если пример выше сохранить под именем prog.py и запустить, получим:

```
$ python prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]

Process some integers.

positional arguments:
 N           an integer for the accumulator

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --sum       sum the integers (default: find the max)
```

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю неплохо использовать метод [getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html).

Вот Вам небольшой, краткий примерчик (всё максимально упрощено, но идея ясна):

```
import sys
import getopt

def usage():
    print 'Help!!!'

try:
    options, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'd:o:h', ['debug=', 'option=', 'help'])    
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, value in options:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        usage()
        sys.exit(0)
    elif opt in ('-d', '--debug'):
        debug_flag = value
        print 'debug flag: ', debug_flag
    elif opt in ('-o', '--option'):
        option = value
        print 'option: ', option
```

Comment: getopt это издевательство в мире питона. Не используйте его никогда